# How do I force a liquid positioned div to stop moving at a certain point?

Tags: css

I'm working on a prototype of a website here:

http://www.paulgrantdesign.com/valcomp/index.php

I have a div in the middle that is set to stick in the middle. It's got a given height, so in the css I did

```
#middle {
height: 225px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #56a6c4;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -112px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

It sits in the middle, as required. But when the window gets too small, I don't want it to cover what's above it. Can I set it so that there's always a minimum amount of distance between the top of the window and the top of this div?

Comment: it's the percentages that does it. You wanted to center them vertically but now you're stuck.

Comment: I think I'm just going to have to make the #top and #middle divs a static height. I think that's easiest. Not ideal, but better than trying to work this mess out :) Thanks for the answers.

Comment: what if you combine it with media queries since I guess that's why you want liquid heights.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use media query for this like this:

```
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1000px) {
  #middle {
   color:red;
}
}
```

You can read these articles

http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/ ,

http://css-tricks.com/6206-resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Answer (score 0):

put position:relative on the body.that s a first step. I m trying..hold on..
and bottom--position:absolute. It works! yeah!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't allow #top or #bottom to be liquid at all. They're a static height all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your problem by changing your html like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="topcontent">
            <p id="mobile">Mobile data collection</p>
            <p id="slogan">Collect. Send. That's it.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
</div>
```

Then changing your css like this:

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 350px;
    bottom: 20%;
    top: 0;
}

#top {
    width: 825px;
    min-height: 250px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin-left: -412px;
    overflow: auto;
    bottom: 250px;
}

#topcontent {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

...

#middle {
    height: 225px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #56a6c4;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-top: -112px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

It might need some tweaking to get it exactly how you want it; especially with the `#bottom` div

Comment: Yes, it does what I want it to in terms of making the #top div stay visible, but it really messes up the #bottom div. Not sure it's any easier to find a solution doing in this way vs. my way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the attribute `z-index` to the elements `#top` and `#bottom`, and let them less than the `z-index` of `#middle`.

Comment: That won't work, unfortunately, because in order to make sure that there's no visible bottom to the #top div or visible top to the #bottom div, they're meeting in the middle, and the #middle div is covering the seam up. If I change z-index, I lose the #middle div altogether.